# I want to configure maximum number of machines in MaaS

Tags: juju, maas

I clustered 3 machines with MaaS environment and those machines are definitely have different amount of resources.

(A) 64core with 256GB memory
(B) 48core with 192GB memory
(C) 4core with 8GB memory

The MaaS node configuration was quite successful so I have no problem with juju status.

But everytime I try to deploy a new service on my maas environment, the deployment encounters an error which is indicating a "new" server pending.

I only have 3 servers but juju wants to deploy on "fourth" node.

Is there any official configuration parameter for maas environment to limit the maximum number of machine nodes?

Answer (score 2):

There's no maximum-nodes setting; but to support your sort of use case, in which you want to place your workloads carefully onto particular hardware, you can directly deploy and add-unit onto known machines:

```
juju deploy haproxy --to 0
juju add-unit nova-compute --to 1
```

...or you can add lxc containers to those machines, and deploy into those:

```
juju add-machine lxc:2  # add a new lxc container on machine 2, named 2/lxc/0
juju deploy nyancat --to 2/lxc/0
```

Note that providers other than MAAS do not currently support containers well, but support for EC2 and openstack-based clouds is scheduled for the next for months.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. So it means that to deploy juju bundle over my metal, I should manipulate bundle configuration file adding "--to #" carefully. Right? I'll give it a try.